# how to manage bandwidth and amount of traffic over pptp?

Tags: pptp, traffic

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.4 and using it as internet server , file server and printer server.

The problem is that my company manager decided to limit bandwidth and the amount of data per user per month.for example 100 Kb/s and 5 GB month/user.

Users connect to server through PPTP .

I would like to know a solution to make this limit on the server.

thank you all.

Comment: You could try to configure QOS settings in your router. Or just monitor the bandwidth and set threshold alarms.

Comment: There is no Router in this network !
the only Router is the server that has two network interfaces.
eth0 connected to a switch to connect users to server & eth1 that is connected to internet.
By the way , monitoring is not enough.we need to limit users.